# Java: Why does Set<E> mention all methods in Collection<E>

Tags: java, collections, interface, set

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

Why does Set interface list all the methods in Collection? Aren't these methods automatically inherited by the child interface?

Comment: And why does this trouble you?? Maybe it is for the help of deeper understanding. If you look at the javadocs, the methods are listed there as well...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It lists them all because the documentation is different, even though declarations themselves are the same.

Comment: Does the documentation actually have to be different? Or is it automatically added when the method is implemented/overridden?

Comment: What do you mean, @G_H? The tutorials aren't automatically generated.

Comment: Set "overrides" all the methods in Collection, in order to provide different documentation - which makes sense if Set have more to add to docs and semantics (Which it does). See e.g. [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) on how the docs and interface looks like when an interface does not override all the methods in an interface it inherits from.

Comment: @LordTorgamus They're not? Wow! I was fairly certain there were annotations and meta-annotations to make sure tutorials were generated in 15 languages based on static code analysis! Must've imagined that.

Comment: @G_H The documentation is much clearer if different, even when the change is simply to replace 'collection' with 'set'.

Comment: @KathyVanStone What I mean is: when JavaDoc gets generated, what determines if a method is listed in the "Methods inherited from ..." section or in the method summary? Is it enough that a method is overridden? My guess was it is, since it defines a new implementation on that class level.

Comment: @G_H I think they are mentioned directly if they are listed directly.  Note that as we are talking about interfaces there are no new implementations (that being limited to regular classes).

Comment: @KathyVanStone Cheers. Maybe I should check the specs. Might be doclet-specific, though. Overal I'm trying to be thorough in my docs, but still don't have a habit of using links or properly referring to superclasses.

Answer (score 2):

That link is a *tutorial*, not the API docs.  Try this link:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: actually, I verified it in my jdk (jdk1.6.0_23\src.zip!\java\util\Set.java). It has all those methods even though it inherits them from collection<E>.

Comment: @AsadIqbal Oooh... You wanted to know why it has those methods implemented. Everyone thought you were talking about the JavaDoc. `Collection` is an interface. It doesn't provide any implementation of methods, it only states that anything implementing Collection must provide an implementation of those methods. Save for abstract classes which may delegate the implementation to subclasses. You'll wish to read up on interfaces and abstract classes in Java.

Comment: @G_H Set is an interface too... His question is why list methods in the child interface that are identical to those in the parent, and implicitly inherited anyway?

Comment: @glowcoder Of course... Totally forgot Set's an interface. Trying to be too quick again. In that case, Kathy Van Stone's answer is the correct one. It merely wants to redefine the documentation for clarity. Boy, did this turn confusing fast.

Answer (score 1):

Set works different then Collection - in Set you can have no duplicate entries. If you would just copy methods from Collection you would implement Set wrong...

Like Kathy wrote - documentation is different (because logic/use is different)

[Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29).add():

> Ensures that this collection contains the
>   specified element (optional operation). Returns true if this
>   collection changed as a result of the call. (Returns false if this
>   collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the
>   specified element.) Collections that support this operation may place
>   limitations on what elements may be added to this collection. In
>   particular, some collections will refuse to add null elements, and
>   others will impose restrictions on the type of elements that may be
>   added. Collection classes should clearly specify in their
>   documentation any restrictions on what elements may be added.
>
> If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason
>   other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an
>   exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant
>   that a collection always contains the specified element after this
>   call returns.

[Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).add():

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present
>   (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to
>   this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ?
>   e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element,
>   the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination
>   with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never
>   contain duplicate elements.  The stipulation above does not imply that
>   sets must accept all elements; sets may refuse to add any particular
>   element, including null, and throw an exception, as described in the
>   specification for Collection.add. Individual set implementations
>   should clearly document any restrictions on the elements that they may
>   contain.